# RTX support for Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

Running Cycles on a 2080ti gives me this error: "CUDA binary kernel for this graphics card compute capability (7.5) not found."

After digging around and finding lazydodo's old post I learned that I would have to wait for new kernel rebuilds with the new CUDA 10 toolkit.  Is there an idiot-proof guide to do this?  I'd work on it if someone could point me the way.

If not, is there an ETA on when it'll be updated to support 2080/2080ti cards?

Comment: I would ask this question/for help on the mailing list/blender irc chat. https://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-committers/2018-September/thread.html https://en.blender.org/index.php/Community:Chat

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:** It's possible now!

You have to get a newest 2.79 (aka Official) build from [Blender Builder](https://builder.blender.org/download/). It has CUDA support but the kernels are missing. That's easy to fix, however. Get a CUDA 10-based [Linux build from GraphicAll](http://graphicall.org/1241). Then go to `blender\2.79\scripts\addons\cycles\lib`. Copy the `filter_7*.cubin` and `kernel_sm_7*.cubin` files to the corresponding folder in the Windows build. It should work now :)

Thanks to Carlo Andreacchio for showing this method in a comment on GraphicAll.

---

Original answer:

I tried to recompile Blender with CUDA 10.0. Sadly, the library that Blender uses for initializing CUDA ([cuew](https://github.com/CudaWrangler/cuew)) didn't even recognize the toolkit. Last commit is from 3 months ago, when CUDA 9.2 arrived. We have to wait...

Comment: Since about 20 days ago Blender made it possible to use an RTX card for rendering. Check out [my answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119837/how-can-one-do-rendering-with-cycles-using-an-nvidia-rtx-gpu/119840#119840)

Comment: @Amir Thanks for the link. I edited my answer, as an easy method appeared recently for people who can't build.

Comment: Nice workaround, but keep in mind that this solution does not work since things in recent builds of Blender keep changing and copying the libraries from an older version of Blender might cause crashes. So the only reliable solution is to compile Blender from source.